# cv::gpu::HoughLines is not working properly

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cuda, gpu

I am trying to detect some lines using **Hough Transform** on a `cv::gpu::GpuMat` structure. I have tried using both `gpu::HoughLines` and `gpu::HoughLinesP` but even with extremely low thresholds, I am not getting any results at all. During debugging, I see that the container which should contain the results (`houghLines`) has only zeros stored inside it. The code I have written is given below,

```
static cv::Mat drawHoughLinesOnMat (cv::gpu::GpuMat hough_Mat, cv::gpu::GpuMat houghLines)
{
    cv::Mat output_Mat;
    cv::cvtColor(cv::Mat(hough_Mat), output_Mat, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines_vector;
    if (!houghLines.empty())
    {
        lines_vector.resize(houghLines.cols);
        cv::Mat temp_Mat (1, houghLines.cols, CV_8UC3, &lines_vector[0]);
        houghLines.download (temp_Mat);
    }

    for (size_t i=0; i<lines_vector.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec4i l = lines_vector[i];
        cv::line(output_Mat, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8);
    }

    return output_Mat;
}


int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread(INPUT_DATA_1->c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    std::string imageType = getImgType(input.type());

    cv::gpu::GpuMat mat_input(input), bil_out, mat_thresh, hough_lines;
    cv::gpu::HoughLinesBuf hough_buffer;

    int bilateral_thresh = 15; // 5 == 0.085s; 15 == 0.467s at run-time
    cv::gpu::bilateralFilter(mat_input, bil_out, bilateral_thresh, bilateral_thresh*2, bilateral_thresh/2);
    //cv::gpu::threshold(bil_out, mat_thresh, 10, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::gpu::Canny(bil_out, mat_thresh, 10, 60, 5);

    cv::gpu::HoughLinesP(mat_thresh, hough_lines, hough_buffer, 1.0f, (float)(CV_PI/180.0f), 5, 1);
    //cv::Mat test_hough(hough_lines);
    cv::Mat hough_Mat = drawHoughLinesOnMat(mat_input, hough_lines);
    cv::gpu::HoughLines(mat_thresh, hough_lines,  1.0f, (float)(CV_PI/180.0f),   1, true);
    /*cv::Mat */hough_Mat = drawHoughLinesOnMat(mat_input, hough_lines);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS
}
```

The image I am using is,

[image]

Could someone tell me what it is that I am doing wrong..? Thanks in advance.!

The output of the Canny filter is,

[image]

EDIT:

I have tested on the CPU version of HoughLines and it seems to work just fine.

EDIT_2:

The solution posted by @jet47 works perfectly.

Comment: How does the image look after applying the Canny filter?

Comment: Oh just a sec. I will post it. And it's up.

Comment: What Version of OpenCv are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.4.6 on a Windows x64 machine.

Comment: One thing you could try is to use `cvtColor` to create a Mask and get your gpuMat from there (like in the sample code)[https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/gpu/houghlines.cpp] but this is a long shot...

Comment: I tried that well but no luck. The `gpu::HoughLines` takes only 8-bit single channel images as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use incorrect code for downloading results from GPU back to CPU:

```
lines_vector.resize(houghLines.cols);
cv::Mat temp_Mat (1, houghLines.cols, CV_8UC3, &lines_vector[0]);
houghLines.download (temp_Mat);
```

You use incorrect type for `temp_Mat` - `CV_8UC3`, it must be `CV_32SC4`.

The correct code is:

```
lines_vector.resize(houghLines.cols);
cv::Mat temp_Mat(1, houghLines.cols, CV_32SC4, &lines_vector[0]);
houghLines.download(temp_Mat);
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it needs to be `CV_32SC4` instead of `CV_8UC3`..? I am not entirely clear on that, to be honest..

Comment: The `lines_vector` is a vector of `cv::Vec4i`. `cv::Vec4i` is 4-component vector of 32 bit integer values. So it is a `CV_32SC4`, while `CV_8UC3` is a 3-channel 8 bit values. `GpuMat::download` method check the type of output matrix and reallocate data if type mistmatch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. I had already tried it out and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the Method you are using is outdated (but im not entirely sure).

This is how i would do it(as demonstrated in this [Example Code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/houghlines.cpp)):

```
//d_src filled with your image somewhere
GpuMat d_lines;
{
    Ptr<cuda::HoughSegmentDetector> hough = cuda::createHoughSegmentDetector(1.0f, (float) (CV_PI / 180.0f), 50, 5);

    hough->detect(d_src, d_lines);
}

vector<Vec4i> lines_gpu;
if (!d_lines.empty())
{
    lines_gpu.resize(d_lines.cols);
    Mat h_lines(1, d_lines.cols, CV_32SC4, &lines_gpu[0]);
    d_lines.download(h_lines);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < lines_gpu.size(); ++i)
{
    Vec4i l = lines_gpu[i];
    line(dst_gpu, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, LINE_AA);
}
```

**EDIT** The above uses the OpenCv 3.0 Interface

Comment: This is with the 3.0 interface, right..? I need to get it to work on 2.4.x interface since this is a part of a bigger application which uses cv 2.4..

I have also followed the same example (but for 2.4.6) but I am not getting anything..

Comment: Yeah I think so, I will leave the Answer though for people using 3.0. In your case it seem to be another problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am totally at a loss regarding what's happening. At first I thought it was because the GPU module wasn't built properly but that's not the case since other stuff works fine.